# Adding Padding to Win32 ListView

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I have a ListView in `LVS_REPORT` mode that contains rows of strings. Everything draws properly; however, I noticed that all of the rows are very densely packed.

Is there anyway to simply add padding to the ListView items? I imagine that you could do `BS_OWNERDRAW`; however, I don't really want to go so extreme if there is just a really simple solution that I'm missing.

Comment: Please add [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And it is best to attach some pictures to describe the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what I ended up doing in order to add some space between each element is essentially create a blank `ListView` item between each real one. I don't know if this is the best way to go about it, but it seems to work so far.